# Unable to parse a list of values to sqlite3 DB

Tags: python, sqlite

i am trying to insert a list of values in to DB table created with 3 field. Here is the code I tried

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("C://Users// Analysis//Data_Analysis_DB.db")

c = conn.cursor()

test=[["value1", "value2", 3663]]

string_value=str(test)

a,b,c=string_value.split(',')

c.execute('Insert into Users values(?,?,?)',a,b,c)
```

but I am getting following error

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'execute'

Would be appreciated if anyone can help on this
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting your `c` variable. It was a cursor object here:

```
c = conn.cursor()
```

But then you're assigning it a string value here:

```
a,b,c=string_value.split(',')
```

And then trying to call the `execute` method, which string objects don't have in Python. If you just change the name of the variable that you assign your cursor object to, you should be fine.

```
curs = conn.cursor()
...
curs.execute('Insert into Users values(?,?,?)',a,b,c)
```